# egrep command which shows all the authors and subjects of mails contained in a directory

Tags: command-line, grep

Anyone know of an `egrep` command which will show the authors and subjects of all mails contained in some directory?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like:

```
egrep '^(From|Subject):' *
```

This will match `From:` or `Subject:` at the beginning of a line, which is approximately what you want.

Comment: That looks good, but how will that show From and Subject?

Comment: That's exactly what it does.  Have you tried it?

Comment: Does the star at the end act as a kleene star?

Comment: No.  For the behavior of the star at the end, see the `bash(1)` man page.  Note that the star is *not* part of the regular expression.